# How to make my method work properly?

Tags: java

```
private static void algorithm2() {
    String name = "";
    int high = (char)90;
    int low =(char) 66;
    int letter;
    int direction;  
    do {
        letter = (high + low) / 2;
        String[] choices = { "Before", "This is the letter", "After", "Done" }; 

        direction = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "Is the next letter in your name a(n) \'" +(char) letter
                        + "\' or is it after/before it? ", "Option 2",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null, choices, "Option 2");

        if (direction == 0)
            low= letter - 1; // 

        if (direction == 1){
            name+=(char)letter;
        }

        if(direction==2){
            high = letter + 1; // last guess was too high
        }
        if (direction == 3)
            break;
    } while (direction != 1);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing " + name + "!");
}
```

Guess the middle letter in each sequence of possible letters. The first time, this is m or n. Whenever a guess in made, ask the user whether a) the guess is correct, b) the correct answer is earlier in alphabetical order than the guess, or c) the correct letter is later in alphabetical order than the guess. Adjust subsequent guesses accordingly, always guessing the middle letter in the remaining set of possible letters. When the number of possibilities is even, it does not matter whether you guess the first or the second "middle" letter. When there is only one possibility, that one is the middle choice in a list of one value.

I can't make it work, when the windows appears I click before and shows the wrong letter.

Comment: Surely `low= letter - 1` should be `high = letter - 1` and `high = letter + 1` should be `low = letter + 1`?

Comment: Well what diagnostic checks have you performed? Have you tried debugging? If so, what happened? What incorrect letter is shown? Is the direction being interpreted correctly?

Comment: Indeed, the comment of "last guess was too high" doesn't match the option of "the next letter is after [letter displayed]".

Comment: I try debugging but if it is not one thing it is another issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people pointed out in the comment:

```
if (direction == 0)
    low= letter - 1; //
```

Should be

```
high = letter - 1;
```

Similarly,

```
if(direction==2){
   high = letter + 1; // last guess was too high
}
```

Should be

```
low = letter + 1;
```

Further more, when `direction == 1` you terminate the loop:

```
while (direction != 1);
```

so the user cannot fill in more than 1 character, so you should change it to `while(true);` or `while(direction != 3)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String name = "";
    int direction;
    do {
        int high = (char) 90;
        int low = (char) 66;
        int letter;

        do {
            letter = (high + low) / 2;
            String[] choices = { "Before", "This is the letter", "After",
                    "Done" };

            direction = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "Is the next letter in your name a(n) \'"
                            + (char) letter
                            + "\' or is it after/before it? ", "Option 2",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null, choices, "Option 2");
            System.out.println(direction);
            if (direction == 0)
                high = letter - 1; //

            if (direction == 1 || direction == 3) {
                name += (char) letter;
            }

            if (direction == 2) {
                low = letter + 1; // last guess was too high
            }

        } while (direction != 1 && direction != 3);

    } while (direction != 3);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing " + name + "!");
}
```

Be careful when `high == low`, if user not accept this character, this should be an error.

Comment: It is only giving me about 4 letters for before and 4 letters for after

Comment: @user3269660 Updated my answer, basically, you need two loops.

Comment: It is not giving all the alphabet for some reason

Comment: @user3269660 Updated :), forgot to add the letter when direction == 3

Comment: it is still not giving more than 4 letters. I tried adding more but still been unsucessful

Comment: @user3269660    Did you change your with my code above? WILSON is output as the answer, updated so that you can just put it into main method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69177/discussion-between-user3269660-and-pham-trung).